# Timeout doesn't delay each loop

Tags: javascript

I want to animate my logo and change its color quickly on hover. But it goes through the loop really quickly, as if `setTimeout` didn't work. What have I mixed up?

```
let changeLogoColor = function(color) {
    document.documentElement.style.cssText = `
        --logo-color: ${"var(" + color + ")"};
    `;
    return null;
}

logo.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        colors.forEach((color) => {
            setTimeout(changeLogoColor(color), 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You create all timeouts at once with a delay of 1000 ms

Comment: And you are _calling_ `changeLogoColor`, instead of passing the reference as parameter to setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

All the timeouts will start and end the same time.

You probably want to use the index returned by `forEach` to increase the timeout for each item;

Thanks to [@Jaood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737343/timeout-doesnt-delay-each-loop/76737351?noredirect=1#comment135287097_76737351) for pointing out that [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) needs a function, not the call to `changeLogoColor`:

---

Use the following

```
logo.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        colors.forEach((color, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => changeLogoColor(color), 1000 * index);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This probably doesn't fix the whole issue, since `changeLogoColor(color)` is not part of the timeout callback. The return value `null` is passed as the callback.

Comment: This solution doesn't fix it. No change.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a [mre] to your question to show the issue.

Comment: Seems like you intended to do `setTimeout(() => changeLogoColor(color), 1000 * index);`

Comment: Thanks to @Jaood_xD for pointing that out, please see my edit Malvinka, you'll need to pass a functionRef, not the changeLogoColor call